# php include doesn't find file, but path seems accurate

Tags: php

I save a root directory in a variable `$root`. Then I append the rest of the file's address for an include.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);//gives me nothing btw

$root = "http://myhomedirectory.int/tools";
include ("{$root}/resources/php/includes/authenticate.php");
echo     "{$root}/resources/php/includes/authenticate.php";
```

For some reason the include fails, but when I copy/paste what the echo statement produces, I am taken to `authenticate.php`. I have set permissions on that file to 777. Why would this be?

Comment: are you trying to include remote PHP scripts that are going to be parsed before they get to you ?     include local files

Comment: @lagbox both are on the same server.

Comment: include 'resources/php/includes/authenticate.php'; local

Answer (score 4):

`include()` is used to read file contents of local php files. It starts to search in the include directory, defined in php.ini, and finally ends up with trying to interprete the argument as a relative path.

When you provide an *absolute* path (like http:// ...), the remote server will never return a php-script, but plain html. (Even if it is your LOCAL server, the call using the external adress will not return ANY PHP-Code because the server will parse the file content and return the generated html )

So, to include a php-file on your server, use a relative path or place it into the include directory defined.

---

Sidenode: If you want to include various files from each ohter, you *always** have to define the path relative to the executed script. Assuming the layout:

```
/index.php
/folder1/file1.php
/folder1/folder2/file2.php
```

And you want to include `file2` in `file1` and `file1` in `index.php` (this is the executed script), PHP will perform the following steps:

`index.php` is the executed script, so using `include("folder1/file1.php")` will perform the desired action. But if you now want to also include `file2` in `file1`, you have to *imagine* that `file1` has been elevated to the root directory `/`, so the include from within `file1` will only work, if you have defined the path relative to the root: `include("folder1/folder2/file2.php")` - EVEN if `file1` is actualy located in  `folder1`.

Calling `file1` directly will now fail, because php would search for `folder1/folder1/folder2/file2.php` - That's the reason why putting files into the  "global" include path should be preferred over relative references. (*if* and only *if* you are also calling subfolder'd files directly*)

Generally you want to use `index.php` for all requests - and then all subfolder'd files are relative from the root directory of your website, which allows you to omit the global include directory and working with relative paths in order to split up multiple projects on the same server.

(*AJAX will blow this principle, cause a php-file called by ajax will be executed in it's actual directory and not from the directory containing the file containing the ajax call!)